# Visual Studio 2015 Error when running ArcMap add-in

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, visual-studio

I'm running a simple ArcMap add-in in Visual Studio and am getting this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "ValidateAddInXMLTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
>   ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.MSBuild.ValidateAddInXMLTask.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].   FirstAddIn

I'm using ArcGIS for Desktop and ArcObjects SDK for .NET version 10.4. I obtained my Arc license and SDK via ISO on MyEsri and for this add-in I'm using .NET 4.5.

My issue seems very similar to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150627/debugging-arcmap-add-in-net-4-5-in-visual-studio-2013-unable-to-start-arcmap-e) one as I also got the same dialog box pictured there, but in the accepted answer it has me check **Use Managed Compatibility Mode** and it was grayed out when I tried it. I also had no luck with the other answers. I'm new to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote this [thread](https://geonet.esri.com/message/575436), Visual Studio 2015 "will install correctly, and create projects, but will not allow you to build a project without having VS2013 installed as well."

Comment: As goofy as it sounds, this works. All you need to do is install (or reinstall) VS 2013 and it will build successfully in VS 2015. Hello, ArcGIS!

Comment: An update to this thread states a workaround [here](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012659)   (Download and install the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated) redistributable Package.)

Comment: @JasonMiller the 2013 redistributable download from Microsoft in your link no longer exists. I was only able to find a download [Here](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202013&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads) and even then I had to rename the downloaded exe to "vssdk_full.exe" before it would even work

Comment: Changing Version=10.X.0.0 to Version=10.6.0.0 in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Esri\ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.11.targets works without having to run both versions of VS 2013 on the same machine

Answer (score 3):

I figure some people might don't want to install 2013 along side 2015, this is another simpler workaround that worked for me..

ValidateAddinXmlTask is not that important if you know your XML is good. The easiest thing to do is comment it out in your targets file. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is where I went, and it avoided the issue (note that it didn't fix the problem, just ignores the validation errors by not running XML validation.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't solve the problem, but according to ESRI support "ArcObjects 10.3 does not officially support Visual Studio 2015. It only supports VS 2012 and 2013" from https://geonet.esri.com/thread/120636, but according to another user in that thread you can make it work.

I'm not sure but there is usually a lag between the latest VS and ESRI SDK releases. For what it's worth apparently ESRI has developed compatibility for VS 2015 and ArcGIS Pro https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/09/08/visual-studio-2015-support-now-available-for-the-arcgis-pro-1-1-sdk-for-net/.

Comment: ArcObjects SDK 10.4 requires either VS 2013 or VS 2015, so should be OK here.  See [ArcObjects SDK 10.4 System Requirements](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcobjects-sdk-system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_134116909B4B4DB888C65AF8FC67CAB9)

Comment: Whoops,  I somehow missed that the OP was using 10.4, I didn't realize that was even released. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

When rebuilding an existing ArcMap add-in, I got a similar error after upgrading from ArcGIS 10.4.1 to 10.5.1:

```
The "ValidateAddInXMLTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly ESRI.ArcGIS.AddInMsBuild.SDK,
Version=10.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86. Could not load file or assembly 'ESRI.ArcGIS.AddInMsBuild.SDK,
Version=10.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct,
that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

Thanks to the helpful responses above, I was able to fix this by changing `Version=10.4.0.0` to `Version=10.5.0.0` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Esri\ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.11.targets`.

As alluded to here and in other responses, there are two things to consider: the ArcGIS version, specified in the Version tag and the Visual Studio version, specified in the Condition tag. After I posted my message I built my project in Visual Studio 2012 Express and got the ValidateAddInXMLTask error again. But, adding lines for ArcGIS Version 10.5 and Visual Studio version 11.0 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.dll` somehow, maybe from an older installation, you can use this dll instead of installing VisualStudio2013 completely. I just solved the problem with registering it to the GAC with those steps:

1. Place the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.dll` and its dependencies in an appropriate directory.
2. Open the command line as admin.
3. Go to the directory holding the `gacutil.exe`, often found in a place like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools`.
4. Add the assembly to the GAC with the command `gacutil.exe /i D:\WhereEver\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build my 10.3.1 AddIn in Visual Studio 2015 by doing the following:

1. Open the `ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.11.targets` file in a text editor (in my case, the file is located:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Esri\ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.11.targets`).
2. Copy the block of Custom Build  tasks:

   `<UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="PackageAddIn" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '12.0'" />

   <UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="ValidateAddInXMLTask" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '12.0'" />

   <UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="ConvertToRelativePath" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '12.0'" />

   <UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="ResolveAddInReference" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '12.0'" />`
3. Paste them immediately below and change the `Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '14.0'"` value from `12.0` to `14.0`.

   `<UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="PackageAddIn" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '14.0'" />

   <UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="ValidateAddInXMLTask" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '14.0'" />

   <UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="ConvertToRelativePath" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '14.0'" />

   <UsingTask AssemblyName="ESRI.ArcGIS.AddIns.SDK.12, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86" TaskName="ResolveAddInReference" Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '14.0'" />`

Comment: My targets file already has both the 12.0 and 14.0 lines, but I'm getting the issue anyway.